# Using undetermined coefficients in a system of DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given system of differential equations by systematic elimination:
$$D^2x - Dy = t \\ (D+3)x+(D+3)y=2$$

I'm looking at the solution below, but I'm confused about their "guess" for $x_p$.
Since we have $(D^3 + 4D^2 + 3D)x = 3t + 1$ at $(3)$ below, I would have guessed $x_p = At+B$ since $3t+1$ is of order one, but instead in their solution they have used the guess $x_p = At^2+Bt$. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a "solution below".

Comment: 0 is a single root of the characteristic polynomial of that third order equation so your default guess gets multiplied by $t$.

Comment: What is "(3) below"?  Presumably $D=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$?  You have $(D^2+4D+3)(Dx)=3t+1$ so you should guess $Dx=At+B$, which is of course equivalent to guessing $x=At^2+B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the method of undetermined coefficients, you have to check for overlap between your homogeneous solutions and the proposed form of solutions with the undetermined coefficients.  If any are the same, you must multiply your proposed undetermined coefficients solutions by enough powers of $t$ to remove the overlap.  So if $$y_{homogeneous} = c_1 e^x + c_1 x^2 + c_3 x + c_4$$, and the right hand side is say $4e^x + 5x^2$ so that the proposed solution is $$Ae^x + Bx^2 + Cx + D$$, then you have to multiply the $e^x$ term by $x$, and the polynomial factor by $x^3$ to remove the overlaps, giving a new trial particular solution $$Axe^x + Bx^5 + Cx^4 + Dx^3$$

Comment: Thank you! So I understand that now. If I may, there is another question of the same nature which still gives me trouble despite knowing the above. I have the system $(D^3 -2D^2 - 5D +6)x = 12$, $(D^2 - 2D - 3)x + 2y = 14t + 8$. Now if I solve for $x$ from the first equation, and I get $x_c = c_1e^{-2t} + c_2e^t + c_3e^{3t}$  and also since RHS = 12, my guess would be $x_p = A$, but the solution says $x_p = At + B$.

Comment: That's weird.  Possibly an error on their part?

Comment: The homogeneous solution in a constant coefficient problem can't have $x^2$ and $x$ without also having $1$. (So you should have a $+c_4$ in there.)